# Remove duplicate records of two column of same table sql

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a table as shown below :

```
ID    OrderId   IssueId EmployeeId
1      123        123    12098
2      124        123    12098
3      125        123    12098
4      123        124    12098
5      124        124    12098
6      125        124    12098
7      123        126    12098
8      124        126    12098
9      125        126    12098
```

where against each OrderId there is record inserted for IssueId. Now i want to filter that which IssueId is not matching the OrderId.

i.e Above sample data orderId 125, but issueId 126. I need to filter only this data from the table.

I'm using following query

```
Select OrderId,IssueId,EmployeeId from IssuesTable where OrderId != IssueId
```

i'm getting the following result.

```
OrderId   IssueId EmployeeId
123        126    12098
124        126    12098
125        126    12098
```

Since each order id has got an issueId i'm getting 3rows for missing issueId.

can anyone help me on this issue. ??

Comment: What is your current query? This should just be a simple OrderId <> IssueId in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you just want rows where the `issueId` doesn't match the `orderId`, `where issueId <> orderId`.  That will return 7 of your 9 rows, though.  I have no idea what query you are running that returns 3 rows, what it means to have a "missing issueId" or exactly what results you expect.

Comment: @TTeeple here i'vve edited the question

Comment: Think you are still missing something.  `where OrderId IssueId` that statement doesn't make sense and should error.  Could you rephrase your question? Something is getting lost in translation here.

Comment: @TTeeple - I believe its a typo he missed `<>` operator between `OrderId` and `IssueId`

Comment: @Indian I assume so as well, just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE OrderId = IssueId
```

Here is a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f760/2) showing how only the rows with the same `OrderId` and `IssueId` are being returned.

Comment: This will give me repeated of 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the `orderid` which doesnot match with `Issueid` in any row then try this

```
select orderid 
from yourtable
group by orderid
having count(case when orderid = IssueId then 1 end) = 0
```

If you want to select the `IssueId` along with `OrderId` then use this

```
SELECT OrderId,IssueId 
FROM   Yourtable A 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   Yourtable B 
               WHERE  a.orderid = b.orderid 
               GROUP  BY orderid 
               HAVING Count(CASE WHEN orderid = issueid THEN 1 END) = 0)
```

Comment: i want to fetch both OrderId and IssueId